# Unit test passes, but with error

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase-authentication

So, I've got a probelm with one of my unit tests. It completes with green light, but `ClassCastException` occures. The class, that I want to test looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class AuthManager @Inject constructor(val fireBaseAuth: FirebaseAuth) : AuthContract {

    companion object {
        const val SIGN_IN_SUCCEED = "SIGN_IN_SUCCEED"
        const val UNKNOWN_ERROR = "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
    }

    override fun signIn(email: String, password: String): Single<Result> {
        Timber.d("Email: $email, password: $password")
        return Single.create({ emitter ->
            fireBaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            emitter.onSuccess(Result(isSucceed = true, code = SIGN_IN_SUCCEED))
                            Timber.d("Sign in by email and password succeed")
                        } else {
                            val exception = it.exception as FirebaseAuthException?
                            val result = handleSignInException(exception)
                            emitter.onSuccess(result)
                            Timber.d("Sign in by email and password returned error: " +
                                    result.code)
                        }
                    }
        })
    }

    private fun handleSignInException(exception: FirebaseAuthException?): Result {
        if (exception == null) {
            return Result(isSucceed = false, code = UNKNOWN_ERROR)
        }
        return Result(isSucceed = false, code = exception.errorCode)
    }
}
```

My proposition for unit test looks like this:

```
class AuthManagerTest {

        @Mock
        private lateinit var fireBaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

        @Mock
        private lateinit var authResult: Task<AuthResult>

        private lateinit var authManager: AuthManager

        private val EMAIL = "email@email.email"
        private val PASSWORD = "password"

        @Before
        fun setupAuthManager() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
            authManager = AuthManager(fireBaseAuth)
        }

        @Test
        fun signInByEmailAndPasswordWithSuccessThenCheckIfResultSucceeds() {
            whenever(authResult.isSuccessful).thenReturn(true)
            whenever(fireBaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(EMAIL, PASSWORD)).thenReturn(authResult)
            doAnswer{
                val listener = it.arguments[0] as OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
                listener.onComplete(authResult)
            }.`when`(authResult)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(ArgumentMatchers.any<OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>>())
            val expectedResult = Result(isSucceed = true, code = AuthManager.SIGN_IN_SUCCEED)

            val testObserver = authManager.signIn(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
                    .test()
            testObserver.awaitTerminalEvent()

            testObserver
                    .assertNoErrors()
                    .assertValue(expectedResult)
        }
    }
```

And the error:

> io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to
>   com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task     at
>   io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)    at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onError(SingleCreate.java:97)
>     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:42)
>     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2693)  at
>   io.reactivex.Single.test(Single.java:3104)    at
>   bla.bla.bla.AuthManagerTest.signInByEmailAndPasswordWithSuccessThenCheckIfResultSucceeds(AuthManagerTest.kt:48)

The 48 line is when `test()` is called on `testObserver`. I have no clue, why error occures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look at [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/)'s [Answer](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v2.15.4/src/main/java/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.java) interface:

```
public interface Answer<T> {
    /**
     * @return the value to be returned
     */
    T answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable;
}
```

As you can see `answer` method **returns object**.

In your code:

```
doAnswer{
    val listener = it.arguments[0] as OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
    listener.onComplete(authResult)
}.`when`(authResult).addOnCompleteListener(ArgumentMatchers.any<OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>>())
```

`answer` doesn't return anything, which by default in Kotlin means return `Unit`.

Return `Task` as in [Task#addOnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<TResult>)). Write it as:

```
doAnswer{
        val listener = it.arguments[0] as OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>
        listener.onComplete(authResult)
        authResult
}.`when`(authResult).addOnCompleteListener(ArgumentMatchers.any<OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>>())
```

and it should be good.

Comment: Now it works without any errors, thanks :) Just one thing for someone in the future: when I added `return authResult` to my code, Android Studio underlines this line with error (probably becouse by default, value of the last expression in a lambda body is returned), but if you delete `return` word, it works.

Comment: Edited the answer according to your comment :)